# Seleção de contato em HTML e CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Olá, recentemente estava vendo um site e achei muito interessante um sistema de seleção/filtro na aba de contatos (https://www.evoluaja.com/contato/)

Quando abre a página de contato, é pedido que selecione se é sobre algum treinamento adquirido ou não, cada opção tem uma parte diferente. Como posso criar isso utilizando html e css?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use uma regra CSS como o seletor `~`

```css
.nao,
.sim {
  display: none;
}

#s:checked ~ .sim {
  display: block;
}
#n:checked ~ .nao {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="rd" id="n"> não
  <input type="radio" name="rd" id="s"> sim
  <div class="nao">
    clicou  não
  </div>
  <div class="sim">
    clicou sim
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Poder ser feito com `jquery`, usando a função `change` para reconhecer uma alteração no elemento, `slideDown` para mostrar o elemento e `slideUp` para esconder.

```js
$('input:radio[name="radio"]').change(function() {
    const value = $(this).val();
    $('p').slideUp('slow');
    $(`p.r${value}`).slideDown('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> Radio 1 | 
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> Radio 2
<p class="r1" style="display: none">Primeiro radio selecionado</p>
<p class="r2" style="display: none">Segundo radio selecionado</p>
```

Referência: [jQuery Effects - Sliding](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp)